# The div floating right can't resize the image at its left and it overflows

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The problem that I have is this:

www.dondolomemories.it

When resizing the window the image of the logo isn't resizing until the very last moment, resulting in a horrific two row menu overflowed.

I spent almost 2 hours trying tons of different settings. Can someone help me in figuring out what it's wrong. I simply want that resizing the window instead of overflowing the logo will resize to fit the menu on the right in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your web page, by my inspection, would let the menu items not be showing on default by resizing to page inner width of 1024, I checked the `ul.menu_top`, discovered that in line `1991` in `style.css`,

```
@media only screen and (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    ....
}
```

Changing the `1024px` value to larger like `1280px` seems resolving the overflow-break line issue.

Comment: this is ok, now It's better and I thank you, but I was wondering if there can be a solution to have the image to change and not the menu to disappear (as it does when it touches the image, to avoid overflow)

Comment: How do you mean by 'image to change'?

Comment: the image to resize. By now I solved with a workaround (using a smaller image just before overflowing) but I am not satisfied

Comment: Maybe you can use percentage values relative to inner window size (`15vw` for 15% of inner width) to specify the image size pretty much like @AntonioSmoljan 's example. See [W3's explaination](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#future)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `.logo` a percentage width on smaller screens:

```
@media and screen (max-width:600px) {
  .logo {
     width:50%; 
  }
}
```

That should align correctly below width 600px, of course you can input and width you want and have multiple breakpoints to align it perfectly.

Comment: Thank you antonio, this was the first thing I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work, the image change dimension but the right menu button overflows the same as before